How can i force a projection from a query?
I'm running into an issue where i'd like to use a group by to create a summary of a complex query, but the query fails to produce valid sql by ef core, since you cant group by an aggregate or subquery.
For examples i might have a table that uses the following query;
var q = Orders
      .Select(c => new OrderOverView {
           Id = c.Id,
           Total = c.Shipments.Sum(x => x.Total) + c.Lines.Sum(x => x.Total),
           Cog = c.Lines.Sum(x => x.Cog),
           EarliestDamageDateTime = c.Damages.Min(x => x.TimeStamp),
           ...
      })

I would then like to calculate a sum of these properties, something like:
q.GroupBy(_ => true, (_, values) => new OrderOverView {
       Total = values.Sum(x => x.Total),
       Cog = values.Sum(x => x.Cog),
       EarliestDamageDateTime = values.Min(x => x.Total),
   })

This would produce invalid sql. What i would like to do is put the entire query in a projection and then group by that, the produced sql would look like this;
SELECT SUM(Total) as Total, Sum(Cog) as Cog, Min(EarliestDamageDateTime) as EarliestDamageDateTime
FROM (
   SELECT ... // The query
) MyProjection

Which does work.
Or something similar. Is there a way for me to 'force' a projection like this?
Using mssql (Sql server). I do not want to use client-evaluation.

@Fildor it was a typo :)

It is known EF Core bug. Try to force generating subquery, for example via Distinct, something like this q.Distinct().GroupBy(...)
